# Will there Be any problem if i install vscode and intellij both?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

Will there Be any problem if i install vscode and intellij both ??

Comment: Nope. They both don't edit the config files of the other editor.

Comment: I can't imagine why there would be.  At least not a problem *inherent* to the process of having two applications installed on one computer.  (Hint: You *probably* already have more than one application installed on your computer without problems.)  More to the point... When you *try*, do you *encounter* a problem?

Comment: don't edit the same file in both editors at the same time, save in between and find out if they detect the changes of the other, Notepad++ and VSC do

Comment: If you're going to work on the same project/files from within IntelliJ IDEA and VS Code there shouldn't be any problems in IntelliJ as long as [fsnotifier](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux) is operational in your system.  If files are not updated in IntelliJ you can reload them manually by hitting `File | Reload all from disk` I'm not sure how it works from VS Code side.

Answer (score -1):

I'm running both (on Mac) and have zero problems